# Odoo vs Home made cakephp development

Tags: crm, odoo-10, erp, odoo-enterprise, odoo-domain

I have a customer that needs to deploy a software to manage Expenses, Human ressource, Employees and other needs specific to the scaffolding domain.

I’m trying to convince him that an implementation based on Odoo ERP is faster, more efficient and covers more of his needs compared to a home made development.

So I’m looking for best argument. Especially because there is another competitor who has convinced him that an implementation based on cakephp CRUDs can cover his need.

I have already identified few arguments:

Odoo is fully configurable

Odoo is process driven solution not by features.

Odoo is open source so free of licensing.

Odoo can provide a real traceability of dada with history of changes.

Can you help me build my arguments ? Any documents on this topic?

Regards

Comment: First and foremost, you are asking the wrong question. The first question you should be asking is whether to buy a (in the sense of *any*) product or build it on your own. Which is a general make or buy question. The answer to this question is highly OPINION based, because you don't give any context about your customer.

Comment: For the make or buy decision see e.g. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/make-or-buy-decision.asp

Comment: I wouldn't even argue about features. The factors I would argue about are cost, availability and support. Those can easily be understand by business people (without IT background)

Answer (score 0):

The question regarding the make or buy was clear in my case. The customer is not a fan if licensing fees. So he prefer open source software. I know that open source doesn’t mean free but it how he sees things.

My customer is a medium company acting in scaffolding domain

Regards